# Python Speech Recognition Issue With Audio Playback

Tags: python, audio

**Latest Python**
I am creating a basic speech recognition program in Python as I am learning. However I am having an issue with audio playback. It does work at the start of the script, but then stops towards the end after doing a search.

**Issue**

1. On line 33 the speech does not play audio and gives me an error
2. On line 22 the speech plays fine and I can hear it, but not on line 33

**Image of my Code**
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLtv8.png

**Temp Fix Solution**
I have changed the text to speak to "pyttsx3" and this has seemed to resolve my issue.

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link. Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: error suggest that you don't have permission to read it. Maybe `playsound` block access to file. You may try to use files with random names. OR you may have to wait until it stop playing previous file.

Comment: put code with correct indentations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.